# Using a UICollectionViewCell as an Button

Tags: ios, objective-c, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell, ibaction

how do I set a UICollectionViewCell to be used as a button , that also repeats itself when the function is done.
I want to use the cell as a button to add images from my photo library.
The code extract is the function of the barbutton item I used to add images.

```
- (IBAction)buttonTapped:(id)sender {
_picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
_picker.delegate = self;
_picker.allowsEditing = NO;
_picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
[self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:nil];
}



 - (void)imagePickerController:(UIImagePickerController *)picker didFinishPickingImage:(UIImage *)image editingInfo:(NSDictionary *)editingInfo {
[_images addObject:image];
[self saveNewImageToDb:image];
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:_picker completion:^{
    [_collectionView reloadData];
}];
}




-(void)imagePickerControllerDidCancel:(UIImagePickerController *)picker {
[self dismissViewControllerAnimated:_picker completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: My code extract is from my ViewController.m file , I made a cellbutton model class. How do I get it working from there

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
- (void)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView didSelectItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    NSLog(@"Selected cell = %d",indexPath.item);

    _picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
    _picker.delegate = self;
    _picker.allowsEditing = NO;
    _picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypePhotoLibrary;
    [self presentViewController:_picker animated:YES completion:nil];


}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can implement this function :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{
 // something you do as function "buttonTapped"
 }
```

Comment: Also make sure to include an `if()` or a `switch()` for the indexPath the "button" is at.